# match two cells from two table and check if the criteria is true

Tags: excel, vba

so i'm working on a code in vba i have two tables the first one is

```
    Work
A   
B   
C   
D
```

and the second one is

```
Names   Situation
A   Pending
A   Pending
A   Verified
A   Pending
A   Pending
A   Verified
B   Pending
B   Pending
B   Verified
C   Pending
C   Pending
C   Verified
C   Pending
C   Pending
C   Verified
C   Pending
```

what to do is when the situation is verified lets suppose of the person A is to count the number of the verified and type it in the cell of work and everytime the situation changing to verified i need to increment it

Comment: use `COUNTIFS()`

Comment: sometimes we just need the right direction , thank you so much

Comment: If you solve your own question, and the commenter @ScottCraner doesn't want to write and answer, you should post an answer. Also, please read --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve